# Visual Studio 2013 Crashes When Intellisense Fires

Tags: visual-studio-2013, intellisense

Visual Studio is crashing when Intellisense fires while typing code, this is something new. I have been using VS 2013 for awhile now, never had an issue. I had to turn Intellisense off to get any work done and now I miss it...anyone know why this would be happening?

I haven't changed any settings or done any updates, i'm stumped!

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Your question isn't exactly super-specific, so here's some general advice for troubleshooting Visual Studio problems. **1.** If you know that the problem started after you installed a specific extension or other software, uninstall it. Check whether the problem persists or not. **2.** Temporarily disable all extensions. Check whether the problem goes away or not. **3.** Reinstall Visual Studio. If that doesn't help: **4.** Reinstall the whole OS. :-) If all of that doesn't help (though you might have given up after step 3) seek product support from Microsoft, or file a bug with them.

Comment: thank you for your help..there isnt anymore specific I could have been...this problem has just started and I havent installed anything new or done any updates ...but I will reinstall VS and see if that helps...

Comment: Seek product support AFTER "reinstalling the OS"?  You can't possibly be serious.  Also, of the 20 extensions I have installed, only 1 can be disabled.  The rest either have the option grayed out or only have an Uninstall option.

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem ...about 3 weeks ago I installed an Exstention called Developer Assistant. this exstention has never given me a problem until the other night, after I disabled the exstention the crashes stopped. maybe this can help someone else with the same problem.